# Is there a tool for assisting with ruby/rails internationalization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I'm looking for something that will help me to internationalize an existing rails application using I18n. Ideally it would locate string constants (with parameters) and allow me to extract those into a `.yml` or `.rb` file replacing the original string with the appropriate `t(...)` call. Also, or alternatively, a macro to do the same on selected text. I mainly use eclipse but could use something else for this task (vim?) as long as it is free to use.

There appears to be a [plugin for TextMate](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/Rails-I18n-plugin-translation-on-the-fly-with-TextMate.html) that does the job (though mainly for new code) and I know that rgettext/xgettext will do a similar job for gettext localization but I was wondering if anyone knew of anything to make the job easier with I18n.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a few Gems, github search for 'i18n' in Ruby:

https://github.com/balinterdi/i15r

https://github.com/zigzag/ready_for_i18n

https://github.com/japetheape/gettext_to_i18n

https://github.com/Bertg/i18n_extractor

From my cursory assessment, i15r looks the best and the most up-to-date. I'll likely using one of these soon (chances are i15r) to at least get a starting point - inserting `<%=t "translate me please" -%>` hundreds of times will drive me nuts before too long; this could be a shortcut for the initial phase.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it does exactly what you're after, but you might find DHH's [Tolk](http://github.com/dhh/tolk) project to be useful.

Comment: Thanks, looks good but appears to be more for translating text once your application is localization ready. I'm at an earlier point in the process than this (unfortunately).